# Flutter firebase use collectionGroup with where

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question.
At the moment i working with my firbase.
There i try to get data with a collectionGroup and the parameter 'where'.

My problem:
If i use colletionGroup its work.
I get all data.
But i if i use collectionGroup and where i get a error.

Error:

> FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.)

Here my Code:

```
_getReviewData(_id) async {
    final String _userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

    //collection group all collection with 'product_images'
    var query_product_images = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('review_data')
        .where('product_id',
            isEqualTo: 'id_1631381448137_EcmTNK2hJmN7ScK9gqM5kxN3W412');
  }
```

My database:
[image]

My db path: /review/user_id/review_data/review_id/document

Now im trying to make a collectionGroup at review_id.
I want just take the collection where the product_id is same as in the document the product_id.
Is that possible?

Many thx.

Edit:
Now im add a indexes on firebase.
Im call the id review and give it the sub paramter from db.
[image]

The Error:
[image]

Question:
How i can get these paramters from firebase indexes?
Have i call them or make firebase these automaticall.

Comment: It's a bit hard to be certain, but I think what you're describing should work. What isn't working about the code you shared? Any error messages?

Comment: Hello @Frank, thx for your fast answer.
I got this error: FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.) (maybe its not an error. But i dont know how i can get the data). Maybe you can help me?

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the error message in the question. :)  As that message says, you need to define an index for the collection group query. As the documentation says: [You can create an index through an error message, the console, or the Firebase CLI.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) Did you read that documentation, and create an index for this query?

Comment: Hello @Frank,
i dont found the link to create the index in the error message.
Now i add the index in my firebase console manuel.
But the error is always there.
Should i change the collectionGroup?

Comment: If the error still shows up after the index has been completely created (this takes time, but you can check the status on the console), it's likely you created the index wrong. If you add a screenshot of the index you created to your question, we can take a look. Also always add the latest error message, as that may have changed.

Comment: Hello @Frank, i add the error and a image of my error

Comment: Hi @Frank, thx you. Finally i got it after i add a one field index in firebase console.
Many thx (:

Comment: Good to hear you got it working Zogger  A single-field index for the collection group should do the trick here indeed. Btw: going forward when posting screenshots of the Firebase console, please switch it to English by adding a `hl=en` parameter to the URL.

Comment: Hello @Frank,
thx for the information with hl=en make ez.
Many thx (: